# Selecting a JSON key from another object that contains a different key/value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "urls": [
            "outlook.office.com",
            "outlook.office365.com"
        ],
        "ips": [
            "192.168.0.0/16"
        ]
    },
    {
        "urls": [
            "*.mail.protection.outlook.com"
        ],
        "ips": [
            "172.16.0.0/12"
        ]
    },
    {
        "urls": [
            "r1.res.office365.com",
            "r3.res.office365.com",
            "r4.res.office365.com",
            "xsi.outlook.com"
        ],
    }
]
```

I would like to pull all IP addresses relating to the "*.mail.protection.outlook.com" URL.

The code I currently have is:

```
import json

with open('ips.json') as i:
    ip = json.load(i)

for urls in ip:
        print(urls["ips"])
```

which prints all members of the "ips" array for every object, but I only want the array from the object that contains:

```
[ { urls: [ "*.mail.protection.outlook.com" ] } ]
```

A pure Python (no non-standard libraries) solution is preferable to make deployment to AWS Lambda easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `loop` statment.

```
import json

with open('demo.json') as i:
    datas = json.load(i)

ips = []

search_url = "*.mail.protection.outlook.com"

for data in datas:
    if 'urls' in data:
        if search_url in data['urls']:
            if 'ips' in data:
                ips.extend(data['ips'])

print(ips)
```

**Ouput**

```
['172.16.0.0/12']
```

Comment: You can replace the inner loop with a `ips.extend(data['ips'])`.

Comment: This works when I use my local copy of the JSON data, but using the live data provided by Microsoft via REST causes a "KeyError: 'urls'" error at "if search_url in data['urls']:"

Comment: can you give the link to test ? or give the exact data that you take from REST API

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd added the link to my previous comment, [here it is](https://endpoints.office.com/endpoints/Worldwide?ServiceAreas=Exchange&NoIPv6&ClientRequestId=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7)

Comment: i update my answer, there need to be a `if` statment, because the `object` with id `94` don't have the `urls` key, also i add the `if` statment to check if `ips` key also exist.